# Get Value of text including newline characters

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I want to get number of characters entered in CKEditor. 
Here is my function which is being called within CKEditor events.

```
function EditorTextCount(editor)
{
   //var data = editor.document.getBody().getText();
   var data = editor.getData();
}
```

In the above function *"editor"* is the CKEditor object. When I use `var data = editor.document.getBody().getText()` I get the text inside editor without newline/enter characters. When I use `var data = editor.getData()` I get some extra special characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try use property innerText, if it will work for you.

```
var data = editor.document.getBody().$.innerText
```

Comment: Working perfectly! Thanks @SAZ. I did a workaround to serve my purpose. I am saving data got through `editor.document.getBody().getHtml()` in the database but it caused another issue. Characters were exceeding limit as a result stored procedure droped off characters. Now I'll not have to change table structure change of the field.